# "Thread safety" of appending to single file from multiple processes?

Tags: linux, file, concurrency

Let's say I have X processes opening file Y for appending. Each process only writes a single line (with a \n) at the time (really log entries).

Is each line guaranteed not to be interleaved incorrectly in file Y ?

UPDATE: local attached file system.

Comment: (I know it's not *really* intraprocess threads, but ..)

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200923/are-unix-reads-and-writes-to-a-single-file-atomically-serialized). I'm not sure if it entirely answers your question, but it explains how write operation occurs pretty well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question depends on what type of write is going on.  If you are using standard I/O with buffering, which is typically most program's default, then the buffer will only be flushed after several lines have been written and will when flushed will not necessarily be a integral number of lines.  If you are using write(2) or have changed the default stdio buffering to be line or unbuffered, then it will PROBABLY be interleaved correctly as long as the lines are reasonable sized (certainly if lines are less than 512 bytes).