# Are multi-process appends to a file atomic in Python/Linux?

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing, threadpool, python-multiprocessing

I have a bunch of processes saving their partial progress to same file during a long-running program.

A way of doing this safely is using a `multiprocessing.Lock`.

But I wonder if simply **appending** to the file is also safe?

It only matters that each **write itself** is atomic. But the writes can be in any order (each write has data about the process that wrote it).

The following example seems to be working as intended...

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import random
import os

# ----------------------------------------------------------------
def thr_work00(args):
  arg0 = args[0]
  arg1 = args[1]

  for i in range(0x3):
    s = random.random()/10
    time.sleep(s)
    print(f'\x1b[92m{arg0} \x1b[32m{s:.3f}\x1b[0m')
    with open('test.txt','a') as o_file:
      o_file.write(f'{180*str(arg0)}{arg1:02x}\n')

  return [arg0,s]

# ----------------------------------------------------------------
if os.path.exists('test.txt'):
  os.remove('test.txt')

tasks = [
  [0, 0xf0],
  [1, 0xf1],
  [2, 0xf2],
  [3, 0xf3],
  [4, 0xf4],
  [5, 0xf5],
  [6, 0xf6],
  [7, 0xf7],
]

with mp.Pool(0x4) as pool:
  results = pool.map(thr_work00,tasks)
  print()
  for res in results: print(res)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Thread safety" of appending to single file from multiple processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514935/thread-safety-of-appending-to-single-file-from-multiple-processes)

Comment: If you go with using your own lock, don't forget to call `flush`. One argument for doing it yourself is this behavior (thread safe or not) is dependent on OS and shell configuration iirc.

Comment: Files are buffered by default.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that they are atomic on Linux, as Python (I checked 3.10, but this should be true for Python 3 in general) opens the file with `O_APPEND` and writes to it with `write`. `man 2 write` says:

> If  the file was open(2)ed with O_APPEND, the file offset is first set to the end of the file before writing.  The adjustment of the file offset and the write operation are performed as an atomic step.

so this is guaranteed to be atomic (there may be exceptions for certain filesystems that do not fully support POSIX).

However, according to https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/59928, for Python 2 this is not true. Also, according to https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/86772, Python 3 on Windows does not support atomic appending to files. The two bug reports above indicate that atomic appending is not something the Python core team had in mind when they designed file handling code, but the situation is improving.